# How to output MySQLi $stmt when $stmt->execute() is crashing my apache server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, mysqli, server

What is the best way output MySQLi $stmt when $stmt->execute() is crashing my apache server? **How can I find out what is going wrong?**

*Problem*: I have a Apache server running on Ubuntu OS website where user selects variables on a form and saves to $_POST variable. In results.php, a sql statement is built and stored in $sql. Intermittently, the website gives the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, particularly on larger responses. The Apache server seems to crash  during the function $stmt->execute(). There are two places in results.php that it runs, and both fail intermittently. Can I just output $sql to the error log?

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt){
            error_log("\t\$stmt set\n", 3, "/tmp/php_errors.log"); 
            if($stmt->execute()){
                    error_log("\t\$stmt executed\n", 3, "/tmp/php_errors.log");
                    $stmt->bind_result($FIRSTNAME, $LASTNAME, $PHONE, $ADDRESS, $ADDRESS2, $CITY, $STATE, $ZIP, $HOMEOWNER,
                       $AGE, $DOB_M, $DOB_Y, $INCOME, $CREDIT, $NETWORTH, $MORTGAGEAMOUNT, $MORTGAGEAMOUNT2,
                       $MORTGAGEDATE, $LOANTOVALUE, $ID);
```

I’ve added error_logs to document each step, and if statements that should stop if from executing if the previous statement fails. However, it still executes, and does not show any errors in var/log/mysql/error.log. 
**/var/log/mysql/error.log** is empty

The server is giving messages that it is shutting down and resuming normal operations. 
**/var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:18.403816 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15875] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:18.694876 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15940] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:18.694919 2020] [core:notice] [pid 15940] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' zend_mm_heap corrupted
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:49.183657 2020] [core:notice] [pid 15940] AH00051: child pid 15961 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:49.183720 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15940] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:49.620150 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16009] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 18 19:07:49.620192 2020] [core:notice] [pid 16009] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 18 19:08:19.856129 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16009] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Here is the code set for error_reporting

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_log("------------------------\n", 3, "/tmp/php_errors.log");
error_log("b2c_access/results.php running...\n", 3, "/tmp/php_errors.log");

// Error Reporting to find bug causing crashes
function myExceptionHandler ($e)
{
        error_log($e, 3, "/tmp/php_errors.log");
        if (ini_get('display_errors')) {
                echo $e;
        } else {
                echo "<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>
                        An internal server error has occurred.<br>
                        Please try again later.";
        }
}

set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');

set_error_handler(function ($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0)
{
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
});

register_shutdown_function(function ()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error !== null) {
        $e = new ErrorException(
            $error['message'], 0, $error['type'], $error['file'], $error['line']
        );
        myExceptionHandler($e);
    }
});
```

**Columns and Types**

```
Columns of table:
firstname varchar(30) 
lastname varchar(30) 
address varchar(60) 
address2 varchar(60) 
state char(2) 
zip char(5) 
city varchar(30) 
latitude float(10,6) 
longitude float(10,6) 
timezone char(1) 
dwellingtype char(1) 
areacode varchar(3) 
phone1 varchar(10) 
phone char(10) 
phone_cell varchar(10) 
income varchar(1) 
homeowner varchar(1) 
lengthofresidence varchar(2) 
presenceofchildren varchar(1) 
gender varchar(1) 
dob_y varchar(4) 
dob_m varchar(2) 
dob_d varchar(2) 
age int(11) 
maritalstatus varchar(1) 
occupation varchar(4) 
language varchar(2) 
religion varchar(1) 
education char(1) 
businessowner char(1) 
credit char(1) 
investstocks varchar(1) 
networth varchar(1) 
lineofcredit varchar(1) 
creditcardindictator varchar(1) 
creditcardnewissue varchar(1) 
investactive varchar(1) 
investpersonal varchar(1) 
investrealestate varchar(1) 
opportunityseekers char(1) 
donor varchar(1) 
vetinhousehold varchar(1) 
smoker char(1) 
politicaldonor char(1) 
politicaldonorconservative char(1) 
politicaldonorliberal char(1) 
seniorinhousehold char(1) 
tvcable char(1) 
tvsatellite char(1) 
intendtopurchasehomeimp char(1) 
gamingcasino char(1) 
travel char(1) 
exercise char(1) 
dietweightloss char(1) 
autopartsaccessories char(1) 
swimmingpool char(1) 
homeyearbuilt varchar(4) 
mortgagerate varchar(6) 
mortgageratetype varchar(1) 
mortgageloantype varchar(1) 
refinanceyear varchar(4) 
refinancemonth varchar(2) 
refinanceratetype varchar(1) 
refinanceloantype varchar(1) 
mortgageamount varchar(8) 
mortgageamount2 varchar(8) 
mortgagedate varchar(8) 
loantype varchar(1) 
loantype2 varchar(1) 
interestrate varchar(6) 
interestrate2 varchar(6) 
loantovalue varchar(3) 
md5_match_key binary(32) 
dnc tinyint(4) 
ID int(11) AI PK
```

/var/error_log/

```
[Tue Feb 18 10:33:54.085090 2020] [:error] [pid 21542] [client 25.255.2.25:34047] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/phpmyminiadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:33:55.733002 2020] [:error] [pid 21542] [client 25.255.2.25:52955] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/phpminiadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:33:57.367823 2020] [:error] [pid 21543] [client 25.255.2.25:38595] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/PHPMINIADMIN.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:33:58.995800 2020] [:error] [pid 21537] [client 25.255.2.25:60031] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/miniadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:34:00.645425 2020] [:error] [pid 21542] [client 25.255.2.25:51185] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/myadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:34:02.285216 2020] [:error] [pid 21543] [client 25.255.2.25:25137] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/dbadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:34:03.914024 2020] [:error] [pid 21537] [client 25.255.2.25:37859] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/phpadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:34:05.555993 2020] [:error] [pid 21542] [client 25.255.2.25:44265] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/adm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Feb 18 10:34:07.190802 2020] [:error] [pid 21543] [client 25.255.2.25:48471] script '/var/www/html/XXXXXXXX.com/PHPminiadmin.php' not found or unable to stat
```

My best strategy to fix this bug is to get outputs of the sql statements and run them in MySQL Workbench to see if I can get relevant information.

Comment: Enable error reporting E_ALL

Comment: Are you using php-fpm or mod_php? this is important i think

Comment: what are the column types in the table?

Comment: You cannot debug this within PHP, because PHP itself dies because of a memory corruption: Segmentation fault. PHP does not work well in apache-mpm-prefork. If you can, use another setup. Ideas: 1. try php-fpm. 2. you can always debug print _all_ the statements before execution and a success afterwards. Find the entries in the log without a corresponding success message.

Comment: Also PHP 5.5.9 is a very old and unsupported version. Are your aware of this?

Comment: Also i dont think you will get any insights from the query itself, because it is some bug in PHP/mysqli that is causing the crash.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that PHP 5.5.9 is unsupported and I would love to do an overhaul. This is a client's server unfortunately, so I'm not able to change the setup.

Comment: Okay. The problem is: error handling/catching/shutdown-function etc won't help you here. If you can't easily reproduce the crash, you need to carefully pin down the activity that is causing the crash condition. As already said: you can log all SQL queries before execution and a success message afterwards, then all you need is read a lot of logs and find the entry without a success message. You can write a script to do that. :D

Comment: I have added error_log comments after every statement and they stop right before $stmt->execute() and the comments after that statment never print. So I've pinpointed the function that is causing the crash condition. Being that is was an execution of a query, I was thinking some type of problem in the query would have become apparent.

Comment: @TylerTrahan No i don't think so. The query is just passed to the DB engine and processed there. It must be a problem with mysqli passing the resultset. But reassure yourself: `debug_print($sql)` before every `execute()` and try in workbench. Maybe you find anomalies in the resultset.

Comment: @Kaii: Thanks, I'll try and update with my results.

Comment: The queries, even ones that were never executed, worked on MySQL Workbench. So back to square 1. I found these errors however,

Comment: Are you using cursors?

Comment: You can at least run this code on a supported version and show a client it works

Comment: @Dharman, no, the code does not have any settings for cursors. Would this help decrease the memory usage and script time. Max_execution_time is set to 600 seconds, but one of the queries I ran took 547 seconds, so they are pushing it.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - We are in discussions to move to a supported version if the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I asked, because cursors are broken in mysqli, so I thought maybe the same is the problem here.

Comment: You should consider moving to supported version as soon as possible even if it is not the solution to the problem. Using unsupported version is irresponsible; you are putting your customers at risk.

Comment: Have you tried without `bind_result()`? Use `get_result()` instead.